# Worksheet Function in Excel Vba with concatenated values

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

I have the following formula:

```
 dim functionString as String

 functionString = "IFERROR(AND(MATCH(" & FirstName.Value & ",C2:C1048576, 0)>0, (MATCH(" & LastName.Value & ",B2:B1048576, 0)>0)), MAX(A2:A1048576)+1)"
```

What I want to be able to do is call it from the VBA code so it would look like.

```
 application.WorksheetFunction(functionString)
```

I know that I can place it on the worksheet at some cell that's never going to be used: IE:

```
 Activesheet.range("ZZ1000").formula = "="& functionString
```

and then reference that cell without worrying whether the program would inadvertently crash; but is there a way to do such a formula from VBA directly?

Basically I'm looking to see whether FirstName.Value and LastName.Value (which are defined elsewhere in the code) together are in the worksheet in column B and column C. As I'm writing this, I realized I need to make sure that they are both in the same row as well and not in different rows.

Comment: Try `Application.Evaluate(functionString)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try `Application.Evaluate(functionString)` but depending on complexity it may be better to use VBA functions instead of WorksheetFunctions.

The `Application.Match` function will return an error type if the value is not found in the range/array, so we `Dim first, last` as variant type to allow for this (without *raising* an error).

```
Dim first, last
' find the row where FirstName.Value appears in column C
first = Application.Match(FirstName.Value, Columns(3), False))
' find the row where LastName.Value appears in column B
last = Application.Match(LastName.Value, Columns(2), False))

If Not IsError(first) And Not IsError(last) Then
    If first = last Then
        ' match was found in both columns and on same row
        ' do something else...

    End If
End If
```

Comment: the application.match function doesn't appear when application is typed out

Comment: @bdpolinsky that's because it's late-bound. It's the same as `WorksheetFunction.Match`, except it will *return* an error value instead of *raising* a runtime error in case of no-match.

Comment: Thanks both. Seems like it works. Some more coding to do, but thats for next week.

Comment: @Mat's Mug can i get a tl/dr of late binding early binding?

Comment: @bdpolinsky late-bound calls resolve at run-time, early-bound resolve at compile-time; that's how IntelliSense only works with early-bound calls. Late-bound calls that can't resolve raise run-time error 438 "object doesn't support this property or method".